# How to properly redirect or rewrite Joomla article urls

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, joomla

Some of my article pages are linking to a menu items that uses aliases as the page url. For example: mysite.com/realurl. However these articles can still be accessed via the browser using mysite.com/?option=com_content&view=article&id=xx, where xx is the article id.

What is the best and easiest way to redirect/rewrite all these urls to the menu item alias, seo friendly, urls?

Comment: What is the end url meant to look like?

Comment: So you want `mysite.com/?option=com_content&view=article&id=xx` to be redirected to `mysite/xx`?

Answer (score 0):

the standard way to rewrite urls is to use the joomla router function:

```
echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=xx');
```

This calls the router.php - file for the component in question (here com_content/router.php)

regards Jonas

Comment: How do i enable that router, isnt it enabled by default?

Comment: Yes, router.php in the component is enabled by default. The router for com_content checks to see if an article is connected to a menu item, and if it is, the menu item alias is used as url. An article can also be indirectly connected to a menu-item because the category it is in is connected to a menu item. The reason I mention the router.php - file, is you can look there to see exactly how your url is generated.

Answer (score 0):

This should achieve what you are looking for

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /\?option=com_content&view=article&id=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /%2\? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+) /?option=com_content&view=article&id=$1 [L]
```